# Context switch and mode switch

Tags: kernel

Does a context switch involve a mode switch? I think it should because the way I'm thinking about this is that whenever a context switch occurs, it involves referring to PCB to know any saved state for the process to run. And since PCB is stored in memory and as only kernel can access memory, a mode switch has to be performed. Am I right?

P.S: I'm not asking if a mode switch involves a context switch. (It may or may not)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a context switch implies a mode switch, since it is the kernel that switches execution from one process to another. A context switch involves restoring the state of the process that will resume execution, including memory mappings, registers, etc., and all this can only be done in kernel mode.

Answer (score 2):

There is a context switch without a mode switch:
Let's take two processes that are currently running on the CPU and each one of them is handling a syscall, thus, running in privileged mode. Now, it might be that the process scheduler will decide to make a context switch between them. Since they both run in privileged mode and the process that is responsible for the context switch is running in privileged mode as well, then the context switch between the 2 processes won't include a mode switch.